# Traefik Ingress not work with dns in my /etc/hosts

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I create a controller Ingress by traefik documentation using a DaemonSet

https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/

So I changed my /etc/hosts for [image]

When I try access in my browser http://traefik-ui.minikube/

[image]

Comment: Hi, try to connect with incognito mode, could be a dns cache issue

Comment: still doesn't work, I changed the DNS in my station and ingress to

Comment: Do I need to have any service on port 80? for ex telnet localhost 80?

Comment: you need to bound the url to the minikube IP , not to the localhost

Comment: as you can here `echo "$(minikube ip) traefik-ui.minikube" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`

Comment: I'm not using minikube,

Comment: The telnet in localhost was inside my master kubernetes, on ip 10.0.1.104, Is it correct that there is nothing on port 80 of my master?

Comment: you can run `sudo ss -tulpn`  or `sudo netstat -tulpn`to check who is using the port 80

Comment: nobody, ```[webapp@srvapih projetos]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.104:2380         0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       9004/etcd           
tcp6       0      0 :::30480                :::*                    OUÇA       14591/kube-proxy ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192963/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-felipe-flores).